# Run an exe and close the command prompt

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

`"subfolder\program to run.exe"` works but keeps the command prompt open.

I would like the command prompt to close but keep the application open, how do I do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answer works fine for me in XP, but you can also try the following instead:

> start "" "subfolder\program to run.exe" & exit

Comment: This worked but the answer by benshepherd doesn't...are you able to explain why?

Comment: Not sure. As I mentioned above, the other one worked fine too for me on XP, and I tested both methods with calc as well as a non-Microsoft program. Perhaps the problem lies with the specific program you're testing with.

Comment: I guess I’m just pushing the question a few inches, but it seems to come down to whether you get your “Command Prompt” prompt back immediately after you type *program_name*, or do you have to wait until it terminates.  Typically, if you type `calc` or `notepad`, you get your prompt back immediately.  But I’ve seen it work the other way for some programs (e.g., Microsoft Office) ***on some machines***.  I don’t know why.  (continued…)

Comment: …  And, if you have a program that locks up the prompt, any commands you put after it (e.g., `& exit`) will be processed only after the program finishes.  And the `start` command, among other things, seems to “detach” the program from the command interpreter, allowing you to get the prompt back (and, hence, allowing the `exit` command to be processed) immediately.

Comment: @Scott: `start` of course can `/wait` for a program to terminate as well. You're most likely correct in that the OP's program probably wasn't returning control back to the command prompt for the `exit` command to be executed successfully.

Answer (score 6):

You can append `& exit` to the command you run. So for instance, from the command prompt:

```
calc & exit
```

runs Calculator and closes the commmand prompt window.

Comment: This does not work. The command prompt is still open whilst the application is.

Comment: What OS are you using? It works for me in Win7 and XP.

Comment: I am running Windows XP